# Pandas change value of column if other column values don't meet criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame. I want to check the values of each row for the columns of "mental_illness", "feeling", and "flavor". If all the values for those three columns per row are less than 0.5, I want to change the corresponding value of the "unclassified" column to 1.0.

```
      sent_no    pos      unclassified  mental_illness  feeling  flavor  
0        0      word_1           0.0            0.75     0.30    0.28   
1        1      word_2           0.0            0.17     0.72    0.16   
2        2      word_3           0.0            0.19     0.38    0.16   
3        3      word_4           0.0            0.39     0.20    0.14   
4        4      word_5           0.0            0.72     0.30    0.14
```

Expected result:

```
      sent_no    pos      unclassified  mental_illness  feeling  flavor  
0        0      word_1           0.0            0.75     0.30    0.28   
1        1      word_2           0.0            0.17     0.72    0.16   
2        2      word_3           1.0            0.19     0.38    0.16   
3        3      word_4           1.0            0.39     0.20    0.14   
4        4      word_5           0.0            0.72     0.30    0.14
```

How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) and [`.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) over `axis=1`:

```
m = df[['mental_illness', 'feeling', 'flavor']].le(0.5).all(axis=1)

df['unclassified'] = m.astype(int)
```

---

```
   sent_no     pos  unclassified  mental_illness  feeling  flavor
0        0  word_1             0            0.75     0.30    0.28
1        1  word_2             0            0.17     0.72    0.16
2        2  word_3             1            0.19     0.38    0.16
3        3  word_4             1            0.39     0.20    0.14
4        4  word_5             0            0.72     0.30    0.14
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
mask1 = df["mental_illness"] < 0.5
mask2 = df["feeling"] < 0.5
mask3 = df["flavor"] < 0.5

df.loc[mask1 & mask2 & mask3, 'unclassified'] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
data.unclassified = data[['mental_illness', 'feeling', 'flavor']].apply(lambda x: x.le(0.5)).apply(lambda x: 1 if sum(x) == 3 else 0, axis = 1)
```

output

```
   sent_no  pos     unclassified    mental_illness  feeling     flavor
0        0     Word_1       0        0.75            0.30       0.28
1        1     Word_2       0        0.17            0.72       0.16
2        2     Word_3       1        0.19            0.38       0.16
3        3     Word_4       1        0.39            0.20       0.14
4        4     Word_5       0        0.72            0.30       0.14
```